# xrandr commands from gdm

Tags: xrandr, gdm3

on debian to use my two monitors I have to run (from a running X):

```
$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
```

and:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --primary --pos 0x0 --output VGA-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0
```

How can I make gdm run those commands for me so I don't have to type them every time?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shell script and place it in `~/.config/autostart` (create the directory manually if it doesn't exist) so it is executed after GDM starts.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --primary --pos 0x0 --output VGA-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0
```

Make sure to make the shell script executable with `chmod u+x`.

Comment: This can be done in /etc/gdm3/ folders, based on when you want your script to execute: https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#scripting